# How do I force pip to update on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying the command.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then I receive the error message:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: (mypath)
Consider using the '--user' option or check permissions.

I've tried the command as admin still get the same error.

Comment: have you tried using the --user option ? `pip install --upgrade pip --user`

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried the command as admin, did you try running the command from an admin powershell? Command runs on my machine from Admin Powershell. do this: search 'powershell' in start>rightclick>click 'run as admin', then try your command again.